# jQuery console.log() doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, firefox, console.log

I'm working in jQuery 3.1.0 and I want to use the `console.log()` function to debug my code (I use the default developer console in Firefox 47.0).

I tried the following code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log($("body").height());
        alert($("body").height());
    });
</script>
```

(The `<script>` elements are in the `<body>` element (at the end, just before `</body>`.)

When trying to run the page, I get the alert with the correct number, but the console is empty. When i tried to type in `console.log('foo');` into the command line, it responds `undefined`:

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1qS5.png)

(I'm sorry for my terrible English.)

**Edit:** I now tried with the following code, but it still doesn't seem to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            console.log('hi');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure you have Javascript enabled

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Javascript is enabled, because the `alert()` function works correctly.

Comment: Looks like you have a script which overrides console.log

Comment: @VitaliiPetrychuk It doesn't work, even if `console.log()` is the only JavaScript on the page.

Comment: @waran how about trying "private mode" in FF and Google Chrome? Maybe you have some extensions installed that modify the window. No other ideas.

Comment: @VitaliiPetrychuk Now tested: It doesn't work in "private mode", disabling all extensions didn't help. I'll try to start Firefox with a new profile.

Comment: @waran, Check my answer below

Comment: @JesusGonzalez Your answer worked, thanks a lot! (And thanks to VitaliiPetrychuk for the ideas.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must enable `Zurnal` option (grey circle) in the top tab where `CSS`, `JS`, ... in the developer console.

Else, you will not get log output.

In spanish is `Registro`. In english it will be something like `Registry/Logs`.